# Data from different months into one chart, colored differently?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have three sheets with pivot tables in one Excel document.
These table different slightly from month to month:

**table 1 - Jan**

bike 100

scooter 20

**table 2 - Feb**

bike 20

skateboard 2

hoverboard 1

**table 3 - Mar**

auto 3

bike 30

I want to create a single graph(pie chart or bar chart) which would show this data together, coloring every month in different color to compare the sales of each product type(some products are not listed in some months).
How to go about doing that?

Comment: I tried consolidating data but that just sums everything up. I'm stuck at figuring out how to show monthly differences on a graph.

Answer (score 0):

create a consolidate sheet from your different pivot table and create your chart from there.

I just test quickly with a consolidated table (done in 5 column for a semi dynamic entry), a pivot table based on this to easily arrange data for the chart. This pivot table is the quick solution but could be avoided with an other arrangement of consolidation (no time for it now)

here are the formula i use

consolidate table

```
A1->E1: sheet   index   month   object  count
```

A2 -> E1000 are formula, same formula per column, so B4 have same formula as B999 (with relative adress inside when used)

```
A2: name of the sheet (sheet that have a serie of data for a month).
```

Manual entry, i use pack of 10 entry per month but it's at your discretion and could be 5 for jan, 22 for feb, 1 for mar, ...

```
B2: =MATCH(A2;$A$2:$A$1000;0)-1
```

`$A$2:$A$10000` is covering the whole consolidated entry of sheet name. It allow to restart later reference used in data

```
C2: =INDIRECT("'" & $A2 & "'!$B$1")
```

where `$B$1` is the local cell that contain the month reference in pivot table sheet (like 1-jan)

```
D2: =INDIRECT("'" & $A2 & "'!" & ADDRESS(ROW(A4)-$B2;COLUMN(A4);1))
```

where `A4` is the local cell that contain the object type in pivot table sheet (like bike, auto, ...)
A4 should be sheetname!A4 but because it's relative row, sheet name could be omit in the formula

```
E2: =INDIRECT("'" & $A2 & "'!" & ADDRESS(ROW(B4)-$B2;COLUMN(B4);1))
```

where `B4` is the local cell that contain the count in pivot table sheet (like b20, 100, ...)

here is a sample of A11:E15

```
m1  0   1-jan   0   0
m2  10  2-feb   bike    20
m2  10  2-feb   hoverboard  1
m2  10  2-feb   skateboard  2
m2  10  2-feb   0   0
```

m1 and m2 are the name of 2 sheet with pivot table data

the pivot table is something like (and graph is based on this) using data from column C, D and E:

`Row Labels  0   bike    hoverboard  scooter skateboard  auto    Grand Total
1-jan               0   100               20        120
2-feb           0   20  1       2       23
3-mar               0   30              3   33
Grand Total 0   150 1   20  2   3   176`

Comment: I don't quite understand any of this. Except for the consolidate part.